# Convert string to date on render of md-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I have many resources returned from my API that require date strings to be converted to Date objects, so that they can be rendered by md-datepicker (Angular Material).

At first, I just did this within each service (in fact, I called another service from each service, that converted the strings to dates), but this is becoming hard to maintain.

So I am trying to achieve this by extending the md-datepicker directive, but I don't know how to modify the value - and each usage will have a different parent controller.

Here's what I've got:
**app.js**

```
.directive('customDatePicker', function(DatesService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'mdDatepicker',
        scope: {
            date: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller, transcludeFn) {               
            // access value in scope here 
            console.log(scope);
        }
    }
})
```

**edit-task.html**

```
<md-datepicker custom-date-picker date="TaskDetailCtrl.task.start_date" ng-model="TaskDetailCtrl.task.start_date">
</md-datepicker>
```

I thought by using an isolate scope I'd be able to get the value more easily - and it not matter which controller was being used (without the scope option, I can see the value but have to know the name of the controller).

Unfortunately, [I get a Multiple Directive Resource Contention Error.](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=customDatePicker&p1=%20(module:%20ICP_App)&p2=mdDatepicker&p3=%20(module:%20material.components.datepicker)&p4=new%2Fisolated)

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Cant you do TaskDetailCtrl.task.start_date = new Date(<your start date source>) ? in your controller

Comment: But the same would need to be duplicated across multiple controllers and services. We have lists of tasks, single tasks, tasks that move / update, other resources that require the dates to be converted.

Comment: Rather than `customDatePicker` as your directive choose a name `mdDatepicker` and rest everything stays the same the scope and require the same check what happens and restrict as `E`

Comment: @joyBlanks not sure what you are saying here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add formatter via attr directive

```
.directive('myDate', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ngModelCtrl){
          ngModelCtrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue){
              return modelValue && new Date(modelValue);
          });
      }
   };
})
```